# jQuery loading is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is as follows. In total I am working with three different page, which are called admin_home_page.php, student_panel.php and nav.js. For the first page the code is given below:

```
<div style="text-align:center" class= "table_space" >    
        <table  align="center" border = "0" >           
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form class="click" action="admin/students/student_panel.php" >
                      <input class="buton1" type = "button" value= "Studentet" />
                    </form> 
                </td>

                <td>
                    <form class="click" action="admin/books/books_panel.php">
                        <input class = "buton1" type = "button" value= "Librat" />
                    </form>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <form class="click" action="admin/staf/staf_panel.php">
                        <input class = "buton1" type = "button" value= "Stafi" />
                    </form>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <form class="click" action="admin/other/more_panel.php">
                        <input class = "buton1" type = "button" value= "Te tjera" />
                    </form>
                </td>


            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>


    <div id = "computing_area_id" class = "computing_area" > </div>



    <div id="action_area" class="actions">

    </div>






    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/js/nav.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="profile/js/nav.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/students/js/nav.js"></script>
```

For the second page, student_panel.php, here is the code:

```
<body >



        <p><a id="add" href="admin/students/student_computing.php" class="student_button" onclick="Print();">Shto Student</a></p>
        <p><a id="delete" href="admin/students/student_computing.php" class="student_button" onclick="();">Fshi Student</a></p>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="admin/students/js/nav.js"></script> 
 </body>
```

And for the third one, nav.js, here is the code:

```
 $('.student_button').click(function(){
  var href=$(this).attr('href');
  $('#computing_area').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');


  return false; 
 });
```

What happens to me is, when i click Studentet button I load only a part of the admin_home_page.php page which is action_area and then in this part of a page are shown two links Shto Student and Fshi Student. When I click to the Shto Student link I also want to load only a part of the admin_home_page.php page which is called computing_area. Now in this part is, computin_area, is supposed to be shown something but it is not.

Your answers are really appreciated by us as we have to deliver our school project within the next two days.

Comment: You are selecting `$('#computing_area')`, but your div id is `computing_area_id` -> `<div id = "computing_area_id" class = "computing_area" >`, not `computing_area` which is your div class. So try `$('#computing_area_id')`

Comment: Thank you very much @Sean. We forget to swap computing_area_id with computing_area.